# iptables limit for every ip address

Tags: linux, iptables

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --sport 1234 -m limit 50/s -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --sport 1234 -j DROP
```

I think if I use the config above, it will limit xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234 with 50p/s, but my target is to limit 50p/s for every ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234 send to.

Can iptables do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure... Try: don't specify the `-s` option. Put a `-i` with the interface name receiving the traffic and it will apply for all ips. And if you remove the `-i`, it will apply more globally for all interfaces.

Anyway, the `limit 50/s` means `Maximum average matching rate in seconds`. If you put `--limit-burst 1` for example, it means `Maximum initial number of packets to match`

Read this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/